# Mock DateTime.UtcNow for Unit Testing in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, datetime, .net-6.0

I'm trying to mock the `DateTime.UtcNow` in a unit test, using [Pose](https://github.com/tonerdo/pose), but it seems that is not working in .NET 6.
The code looks like this:

```
// Arrange
...
var created = DateTime.UtcNow;
var expectedRequest = new ExpectedRequest()
{
    Created = created
    ...
};

var shim = Shim.Replace(() => DateTime.UtcNow).With(() => created);

PoseContext.Isolate(() =>
{
    // Act
    var mappedRequest = request.ToExpectedRequest();

    // Assert
    mappedRequest.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedRequest);
}, shim);
...
```

The problem is that the unit test is stuck when `PoseContext.Isolate(()` is reached and when I try to stop the unit test, Visual Studio freezes and restarts itself.

Is there any other option or library similar to [Pose](https://github.com/tonerdo/pose)?

I know that the most common approach is to introduce an interface that the application logic will use instead of the direct use of `DateTime.UtcNow` property, but I don't want to inject a new service just for that and I'm trying to find a solution without modifying the implementation.

**Edit:**
There are multiple ways to 'solve' this mocking problem for `DateTime` that can be found [here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/5-ways-to-mock-datetime-now-for-unit-testing-in-c-bf0438eab032) or [here](https://methodpoet.com/unit-testing-datetime-now/), but I choose the Ambient Context [approach](https://dvoituron.com/2020/01/22/UnitTest-DateTime/).

The unit test looks like this now:

```
// Arrange
...
using var context = new DateTimeProviderContext(DateTime.UtcNow);
var expectedRequest = new ExpectedRequest()
{
    Created = DateTimeProvider.UtcNow
    ...
};

// Act
var mappedRequest = request.ToExpectedRequest();

// Assert
mappedRequest.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedRequest);
...
```

In the implementation the only thing left to do was to use `Created = DateTimeProvider.UtcNow` instead of `Created = DateTime.UtcNow`.

I will add here those 2 classes `DateTimeProvider` and `DateTimeProviderContext` in case someone needs them.

```
public static class DateTimeProvider
{
    public static DateTime Now
        => DateTimeProviderContext.Current == null
        ? DateTime.Now
        : DateTimeProviderContext.Current.ContextDateTime;

    public static DateTime UtcNow => Now.ToUniversalTime();
}
```

```
public class DateTimeProviderContext : IDisposable
{
    internal DateTime ContextDateTime;
    private static readonly ThreadLocal<Stack> _threadScopeStack = new(() => new Stack());
    private bool _isDisposed = false;

    public DateTimeProviderContext(DateTime contextDateTime)
    {
        ContextDateTime = contextDateTime;
        _threadScopeStack.Value?.Push(this);
    }

    public static DateTimeProviderContext? Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (_threadScopeStack.Value?.Count == 0)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                return _threadScopeStack.Value?.Peek() as DateTimeProviderContext;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_isDisposed && disposing)
        {
            _threadScopeStack.Value?.Pop();
        }
        _isDisposed = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Creating an interface for this is the only real way that I know of to accomplish this.  Microsoft does it in the .NET code for unit testing purposes.   There is a great video by Nick Chapsas on YouTube about it.